# Angular: Filtrar key de un array de objetos en JSON usando un pipe

Tags: angular, json, typescript, filtro, jsonobject

Necesito filtrar el key "popular" igual a TRUE, para que en el ngFor me muestre solamente los objetos que tenga popular en true.

**Este es mi json sv:**

```
"products": [
    {
      "name": "Bahamas",
      "price": "680",
      "category": "URAMAKIS - ROLLS",
      "description": "Roll relleno de Palta y Philadelphia envuelto en Salmón Rosado.",
      "image": "https://www.sushi-lives.com.ar/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/pieza8-510x340.jpg",
      "id": 1,
      "popular": true
    },
    {
      "name": "New Zeland",
      "price": "682",
      "category": "URAMAKIS - ROLLS",
      "description": "Roll relleno de Salmón y Philadelphia envuelto en Palta.",
      "image": "https://www.sushi-lives.com.ar/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/pieza6-510x340.jpg",
      "id": 2
    }
```

Estuve intentando lo siguiente:

**PIPE:**

```
@Pipe({ name: 'filterArray' })
export class filterArray implements PipeTransform {
  transform(pages: any[], [key] : any) {
    return pages.filter(page => {
      return page[key] === true; // <------
});

  }
}
```

**COMPONENTE.TS:**

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  popularProducts: undefined | Product[];
  trendyProducts:undefined | Product[];


  constructor( private product: ProductService ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
      this.product.trendyProducts()
        .subscribe((data)=>{
          this.trendyProducts=data;
        })
  }



}
```

**COMPONENTE.HTML:**

```
<div class="col-sm-3" *ngFor="let item of trendyProducts | filterArray:'popular'">
            <div class="product-item">
                <img src="{{ item.image }}" alt="">

                <div class="product-details">
                    <h6 class="name-head">{{ item.name }}</h6>
                    <div class="product-price">
                        <h6>Precio: {{ item.price }}</h6>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="product-footer">
                    <a routerLink="/details/{{ item.id }}">View Details</a>
                </div>
            </div>
</div>
```

Pero en el html me entrega el siguiente error: "Argument of type 'Product[] || undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type "any[]". Type "undefined" is not assignable to type "any[]"

**Mi llamada al servicio es la siguiente:**

```
trendyProducts() : Observable<Product[]>{
    return this.http.get<Product[]>('http://localhost:3000/products?_limit=4');
  }
```

**Y mi interface es esta:***

```
export interface Product {
   name: string,
   price: number,
   category: string,
   description: string,
   image: string,
   id: number,
   popular: boolean}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacer esto en tu `component`

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  trendyProducts!: Product[];
  popularProducts!: Product[];
  


  constructor( private product: ProductService ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
      this.product.trendyProducts().subscribe((data)=>{
          this.trendyProducts=data;
     
          this.popularProducts=this.trendyProducts.filter((element)=>{
              return element.popular==true
                })

        })
  }
}
```

y el `html` te quedaría así

```
<div class="col-sm-3" *ngFor="let item of popularProducts">
            <div class="product-item">
                <img src="{{ item.image }}" alt="">

                <div class="product-details">
                    <h6 class="name-head">{{ item.name }}</h6>
                    <div class="product-price">
                        <h6>Precio: {{ item.price }}</h6>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="product-footer">
                    <a routerLink="/details/{{ item.id }}">View Details</a>
                </div>
            </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! Excelente respuesta. Funciono y es mucho mas fácil de lo que intentaba hacer.